# LINQ in SQL - How to sort data and separate by months

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

So I got database with very bad architecture :(

So now I need to write logic for get from table data and I need create List of my class objects from this data - but separate its by month

I have table, and there I have column Date ( 2016-01-12 00:00:00.000 this is format)

So now I want to get data - group by date (because if I have a few record for 1 day - I want to get summ of some properties for 1 day )

ANd I need to create array(List) :

This what I try:

```
public List<DriverPayroll> GetAllPayrolls(int pageNumber, int showOnPage, string DriverNumber)
    {
        Database db = new Database();
        var loads = db .TableA.Where(i => i.Driver == DriverNumber).Skip(pageNumber * showOnPage).GroupBy(o => o.Data);
        List<DriverPayroll> payrols = new List<DriverPayroll>();
        DriverPayroll payRoll = new DriverPayroll();
        int month = loads.First().First().Data.Month;
        foreach (var load in loads)
        {
            if(load.First().Data.Month != month)
            {
                payrols.Add(payRoll);
                payRoll = new DriverPayroll();
            }


            DriverWordDay workDay = new DriverWordDay();
            workDay.Date = load.First().Data;
            var tt = workDay.Date.Month;
            LoadData newLoad = new LoadData();
            foreach (var data in load)
            {
                newLoad.Stops += data.Stops;
                newLoad.Base += data.Base;
                newLoad.Attempts += data.Stops_Atempts;
                newLoad.Total += data.Total;
            }
            workDay.Loads.Add(newLoad);
            payRoll.WorkDays.Add(workDay);
        }
        return payrols;
    }
```

If I understand correct - here I do very stupid thing:

```
 if(d.First().Data.Month != month)
                    {
                        classA .Add(classB);
                        classB  = new ClassB();
                    }
```

Because I just replace pointer in memory, right?

And also I don`t really like how it all looks.

Can you help me improve this code?

Thank you

Comment: How do `ClassA` and `ClassB` look like?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Try using more meaningful names than ABC and CCC so that we can get some sense of what it is that is going on here

Comment: Any idea how to write this part better?